# any guidance on solving 4 equations with 4 unkowns using fsolve()

Tags: python, scipy

Write a p rogram that uses fsolve() to solve the rolling wheel dynamics - impending slip problem shown.

You must use the "args" feature of fsolve() to communicate the wheel parameters. Use all of the wheel parameters posted, except for the static coefficient of friction and the ramp-angle theta. Generate a plot of ramp angle vs coefficient of friction for impending slip, for friction values of 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, up to 0.85.

```
17-94:
The tire has a weight of 30lb and aradius of gyration kG = 0.6 ft.

If the coefficients of static and kinetic friction between the wheel
and the plane are mu_s = 0.2 and mu_k = 0.15, determine the tire's angular
acceleration as it rolls down the incline. set theta = 12 degrees,
radius = r = 1.25 ft.

The set of eqns from this problem are:
Sum_Fx = m*(aG) = W*sin(theta) = (W/gc)*aG
Sum_Fy = m*(aG) = N - W*cos(theta) = 0
Sum_Mg = Ig*alpha = F*r = [(W/gc) * (kG)**2 ] * alpha

Assume the wheel does not slip: aG = r*alpha
```

**Just to note, I am new to python so I am completely lost. Any code with explanation/tips/guidance to initiate this problem would be very helpful**

This is what I have so far (I know its not right btw):

```py
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy import sin,cos,radians
from scipy import linspace
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def set_of_eqns(vals):
    """
    1. Rolling Wheel Dynamics - impending slip problem.
    2. Wheel parameters: w = 30 lb, theta = 12 degrees, F, N,aG, alpha, kG =    0.6 ft, g = 32.2, mu = 
       0.2, r = 1.25
    3. We must use FSOLVE() to solve the problem.
    4. We must use "args" feature of Fsolve to communicate wheel parameters
    5. Generating a plot "Ramp angle vs Coefficient of friction for impending slip
            5.1. Using friction values: 0.1, 0.15, 0.2... up to 0.85
    :param vals:
    :return:
    """
    F, aG, N, alpha = vals # unpacking the unknown values
    W, theta, gc, r,k_G = 30, 32.2, 0.21, 1.25, 0.6 # known wheel parameters
    
    # below are the equations after setting them to 0

    f1val = W * sin(radians(theta)) - F - (W / gc) * a_G
    f2val = N - W * cos(radians(theta))
    f3val = F * r - (W / gc) * k_G ** 2 * alpha
    f4val = a_G - r * alpha
    f5val = F - mu*N
    return (f1val, f2val,f3val,f4val,f5val)

def main():
    (F, aG, N, alpha) = fsolve(set_of_eqns,(1,1,1,1))
    print(F,aG, N, alpha)
```